# Упорядочить список по типу содержимого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список

Есть список: `[1, 3, 5, 'adf', 34, (1, 5, 8)]`. Хочу упорядочить его по типу содержимого, чтобы сначала шли целые числа, строка и в конце кортеж.

То есть получить на выходе: `[1, 3, 5, 34, 'adf', (1, 5, 8)]`.

Как добиться этого?

Comment: Напишите свой компаратор, где будете сравнивать типы елементов. Либо [хороший пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756863/how-to-sort-a-list-of-different-types).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно использовать [сортировку со своим компаратором](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) и для него задать возврат значений как приоритет по типу.

Пример:

```
TYPE_BY_PRIORITY = {
    int: 0,
    str: 1,
    tuple: 2,
}

items = [1, 3, 5, 'adf', 34, (1, 5, 8)]
items.sort(key=lambda x: TYPE_BY_PRIORITY.get(type(x)))
print(items)
# [1, 3, 5, 34, 'adf', (1, 5, 8)]
```

**UPD.**

Чтобы сортировка без ошибок обрабатывала типы, что нет в `TYPE_BY_PRIORITY`, то в `.get` нужно возвращать значение по умолчанию:

```
items.sort(key=lambda x: TYPE_BY_PRIORITY.get(type(x), 99))
```

**UPD2.**

Как подсказал **MaxU**, можно в компараторе возвращать кортеж вида `(приоритет, значение)`, тогда сортировка будет и по типу, и по значению (будет порядок для элементов одного типа):

```
items.sort(key=lambda x: (TYPE_BY_PRIORITY.get(type(x), 99), x))
```

Это заметно с выборкой `[3, 1, 5, 'adf', 34, (1, 5, 8)]`. Компаратор только с приоритетом вернет `[3, 1, 5, 34, 'adf', (1, 5, 8), 2.2]`, а компаратор с приоритетом и значением вернет: `[1, 3, 5, 34, 'adf', (1, 5, 8)]`

Comment: Красиво, хоть на стену вешай )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, спасибо :)

Comment: Можно `TYPE_BY_PRIORITY[type(x)]` вместо `get` использовать.

Comment: @insolor, лучше не использовать, т.к. если в списке появится неподдерживаемый в TYPE_BY_PRIORITY тип, то оператор `[]` выбросит исключение `KeyError`, а `.get` в таком случае вернет `None`. Пример: `TYPE_BY_PRIORITY.get(type(2.3))` и `TYPE_BY_PRIORITY[type(2.3)]` :)

Comment: @gil9red, а ваше решение в этом случае выкинет исключение `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`. Чтобы отрабатывало неизвестные типы, нужно дефолтное целочисленное значение задать в `get`.

Comment: @insolor, вы правы, спасибо за замечание :)

Comment: можно немного улучшить решение, добавив сортировку внутри каждого типа данных: `sorted(items, key=lambda x: (TYPE_BY_PRIORITY.get(type(x), 99), x))`

Comment: @MaxU, чтобы одинаковые типы тоже были упорядочены по своему смысла, ага :) Спасибо, добавлю этот вариант :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам "грязный хак" - по стечению обстоятельств он подходит к вашему случаю:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 'adf', 34, (1, 5, 8)]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: str(type(x)))
print(b)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 3, 5, 34, 'adf', (1, 5, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение "в лоб":

```
d = [1, 3, 5, 'adf', 34, (1, 5, 8)]

digits = []
strings = []
tuples = []

for i in d:
    if isinstance(i, str): # Строка?
        strings.append(i)
    elif isinstance(i, tuple): # Кортеж?
        tuples.append(i)
    elif isinstance(i, int):    # Число?
        digits.append(i)

print(digits + strings + tuples)
```

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica может и элегантно, но читать невозможно

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Я ж "дровосек" - тут все ответы красивее моего и ваш в том числе )

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica да, потому что я сам новичок в питоне )

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение в стиле code-golf. Переменная l это ваш список:

```
[x for x in l if isinstance(x,int)]+[i for i in l if isinstance(i,str)] + [j for j in l if isinstance(j,tuple)]
```

Comment: Как-то длинно для code-golf. `sum(map(lambda T:list(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x,T),L)),(int,str,tuple)),[])`

Comment: @insolor Ну вы правы, я имел ввиду, что довольно коротко и в одну строчку получилось. Конечно, ваше решение лучше. Лучше напишите отдельный ответ.

Comment: В одну строчку может у вас и получилось, но уж точно не элегантно. Ответом оформлять не буду, потому что вопрос не про кратчайшее решение, а нормальное решение уже дал gil9red.

Comment: @insolor Gil9red дал не нормальный ответ, а идеальный.
Я же просто переделал ответ Alexander Chernin.

Comment: Не бывает идеального кода, бывает нормальный. Идеальный код - тот который не написан. По поводу переделки - мое мнение в том что этого не нужно было делать - опять же потому что вопрос был не про code golf. Но это только мое мнение.

Comment: @insolor Под идеальным я имел ввиду наилучший, the most pythonic.

Comment: @insolor Переделку я сделал т.к решение Alexander Chernin хорошо, но хочется записать его экономнее.

Comment: Не нужно писать код экономно, нужно писать нормально. Давайте на этом закончим.

Comment: @insolor Что значит нормально?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081104/1365

Comment: @insolor А я не спорю:это решение лучше остальных, но остальные тоже имеют право на существование.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104322/discussion-between-victor-says-reinstate-monica-and-insolor).

Comment: @insolor https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199560/sort-list-by-types/199565#199565

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 — 15 bytes

```
l.sort(key=dir)
```

Вот уж настоящий code-golf.

Comment: @insolor 15 bytes.